# Is it possible to return js PROMISE value in selenium as the variable?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I do use JS script to get one thing via xmlhttprequests. I need to pass this value back to the selenium where I can proceed further actions. My code returns None all the time, eventhough the global variable has been assigned and returned. I read somewhere that it is impossible to retrieve raw PROMISE value ?

```
    var request = ""

    function send(method,url,data){
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            xhr.open(method, url)
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhr.onload = function(){
                const raw_content = String(xhr.response)
                const start_index = raw_content.indexOf("request")
                const end_index = raw_content.indexOf("</settings>")
                const x_request = raw_content.substring(start_index+("request=").length+1, end_index-3)
                resolve(x_request)
            };
            xhr.send(data)
        });
        return promise;
    };

    async function final(){
        await send("POST", "https://www.thecrims.com/login",data).then((responseData)=>{
            request = responseData
            return responseData
        });
    };

final();
return request
```

When I put the above code to driver.execute_script and attempt to print it, it returns nothing or None. Is there any another way to get this value out of it ?

Comment: Have you tried this from browser console first?  Try printing `responseData` in `final` function. By that way you can figure out if the issue is with the response data or not.

Comment: Let me know if you need any help on testing your code in browser console.

Comment: @supputuri code works but I still can;t return the value in python :( Is it even possible to return promise value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have to make small change to your `final` method.

```
async function final(){
        const val = await send("POST", "https://www.thecrims.com/login",data).then((responseData)=>{
            request = responseData
            return responseData
        });
     return val;
    };
```

This should return the value.

Here is the sample test I did to validate the scenario.

```
jsFunction1 = """window.send =function(method,url){ const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const promise = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            xhr.open(method, url)
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            xhr.onload = function(){
                const raw_content = String(xhr.response)
                resolve(raw_content)
            };
            xhr.send()
        }); return promise }; """

jsFunction2 = """window.final =function(){const val =send("get","https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").then((responseData)=>{
            return responseData
        }); return val}; """

# load the function so that you can call where ever you want
driver.execute_script(jsFunction1)
driver.execute_script(jsFunction2)
value = driver.execute_script("return final()")
print(value)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the promise in the same way as you would use it to declare a variable

```
const value = yourPromise().then(value => { return value })
```

Or in python using selenium:

```py
driver.execute_script("return yourPromise().then(value => { return value })")
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around :) I run alert message with the content of variable and **scrape** this alert with selenium.